# Detecting key press only once in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, input, keyboard

Have a question on keyboard inputs. Currently I am using this method to read my input, `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)`, it is working fine. But I do realized at times there are multiple instances of A being pressed when I only press once. And I understand that the method had to be placed in the `render()` method for it to work. Is the problem due to the refreshing?

My question is, how can I only detect 1 instance of "A", when A is pressed for once.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify myself, when i detected the key then the textfield will be updated with the input.

Comment: Eh, I think i got what you mean, Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

LibGdx library provided an InputProcessor Interface, I think you are better to implement the InputProcessor and you should set Screen's input processor to the class you made, see tutorials that dermetfan user made on youtube
http://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan/videos

however you may would like to use different methods, also check DeviceInfo of LibGdx for checking devices.

Answer (score -1):

store the current keys state, get the new ones and

```
if(newInput.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && oldInput.isKeyUp(Input.Keys.A))
```